# How to plot continous data that depends on column value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

**What I want**

I need to plot a graph like this with dataframe below:
[image]

```
0   Buy 2021-06-15 0:00:00  60
1   Sale    2021-06-17 0:00:00  11
2   Sale    2021-06-17 0:00:00  4
3   Sale    2021-06-17 0:00:00  2
4   Sale    2021-06-18 0:00:00  1
5   Sale    2021-06-18 0:00:00  2
6   Sale    2021-06-19 0:00:00  1
7   Sale    2021-06-21 0:00:00  1
8   Sale    2021-06-22 0:00:00  1
9   Sale    2021-06-23 0:00:00  1
10  Sale    2021-06-25 0:00:00  3
11  Sale    2021-06-30 0:00:00  3
12  Buy 2021-06-30 0:00:00  50
13  Sale    2021-07-01 0:00:00  2
14  Sale    2021-07-01 0:00:00  6
15  Sale    2021-07-02 0:00:00  1
16  Sale    2021-07-02 0:00:00  3
17  Sale    2021-07-03 0:00:00  1
18  Sale    2021-07-03 0:00:00  2
```

I was trying to plot with `cumsum()` but I need to first convert rows with 'Sale' to negative values in order to do that.

Is there a better way to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try something like:

```
# Convert to datetime
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
# Negate Sale rows
df.loc[df['action'].eq('Sale'), 'amt'] *= -1
# Calculate the total amount
df['total_amt'] = df['amt'].cumsum()
# Plot datetime vs total_amt
ax = df.plot(x='datetime', y='total_amt', ylabel='Qty', xlabel='Date')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'action': ['Buy', 'Sale', 'Sale', 'Sale', 'Sale', 'Sale', 'Sale', 'Sale',
               'Sale', 'Sale', 'Sale', 'Sale', 'Buy', 'Sale', 'Sale', 'Sale',
               'Sale', 'Sale', 'Sale'],
    'datetime': ['2021-06-15 0:00:00', '2021-06-17 0:00:00',
                 '2021-06-17 0:00:00', '2021-06-17 0:00:00',
                 '2021-06-18 0:00:00', '2021-06-18 0:00:00',
                 '2021-06-19 0:00:00', '2021-06-21 0:00:00',
                 '2021-06-22 0:00:00', '2021-06-23 0:00:00',
                 '2021-06-25 0:00:00', '2021-06-30 0:00:00',
                 '2021-06-30 0:00:00', '2021-07-01 0:00:00',
                 '2021-07-01 0:00:00', '2021-07-02 0:00:00',
                 '2021-07-02 0:00:00', '2021-07-03 0:00:00',
                 '2021-07-03 0:00:00'],
    'amt': [60, 11, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 50, 2, 6, 1, 3, 1, 2]
})
```

*Column headers were omitted so I added some.

`df.head()`:

```
  action            datetime  amt
0    Buy  2021-06-15 0:00:00   60
1   Sale  2021-06-17 0:00:00   11
2   Sale  2021-06-17 0:00:00    4
3   Sale  2021-06-17 0:00:00    2
4   Sale  2021-06-18 0:00:00    1
```

---

1. Convert the date column [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
```

This will make the xaxis ticks much easier to work with.

2. Negate the rows where the "action" is equal to "sales":

```
df.loc[df['action'].eq('Sale'), 'amt'] *= -1
```

`df.head()`:

```
  action   datetime  amt
0    Buy 2021-06-15   60
1   Sale 2021-06-17  -11
2   Sale 2021-06-17   -4
3   Sale 2021-06-17   -2
4   Sale 2021-06-18   -1
```

3. Calculate the cumulative total with [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['total_amt'] = df['amt'].cumsum()
```

```
  action   datetime  amt  total_amt
0    Buy 2021-06-15   60         60
1   Sale 2021-06-17  -11         49
2   Sale 2021-06-17   -4         45
3   Sale 2021-06-17   -2         43
4   Sale 2021-06-18   -1         42
```

4. Then [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with "datetime" on the x-axis and "total_amt" on the y-axis:

```
ax = df.plot(x='datetime', y='total_amt', ylabel='Qty', xlabel='Date')
```

---

Another optional step could be to plot only the ending total per day using [`groupby last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
# Convert to datetime
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
# Negate Sale rows
df.loc[df['action'].eq('Sale'), 'amt'] *= -1
# Calculate the total amount
df['total_amt'] = df['amt'].cumsum()
# Get only the Ending Daily Total
daily_df = df.groupby(df['datetime'].dt.date)[['datetime', 'total_amt']].last()
ax = daily_df.plot(x='datetime', y='total_amt', ylabel='Qty', xlabel='Date')
plt.show()
```

`daily_df.head()`:

```
             datetime  total_amt
datetime                        
2021-06-15 2021-06-15         60
2021-06-17 2021-06-17         43
2021-06-18 2021-06-18         40
2021-06-19 2021-06-19         39
2021-06-21 2021-06-21         38
```

[image: plot 2]

Comment: I opened one more question very similar to this one, could you take a look and see if can help me? Thank you for your help!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68270492/how-to-plot-continous-data-with-grouping