# How to plot continous data with grouping

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

**What I want**

I want to plot a graph for each `cod` item. ex: `1746`, `202` ... etc

But as shown in the graph I only have one graph for one item.

I want to show more graphs for each `cod`.

[image]

**Dataframe I have**

```
    cod action  date    qty
0   1746    buy 2021-06-15 0:00:00  45
1   202 buy 2021-06-15 0:00:00  60
2   1746    sell    2021-06-17 0:00:00  1
3   1746    sell    2021-06-17 0:00:00  3
4   1746    sell    2021-06-17 0:00:00  7
5   202 sell    2021-06-17 0:00:00  1
6   202 sell    2021-06-17 0:00:00  3
7   1746    sell    2021-06-18 0:00:00  1
8   1746    sell    2021-06-18 0:00:00  1
9   1746    sell    2021-06-18 0:00:00  1
10  1746    sell    2021-06-18 0:00:00  1
11  1746    sell    2021-06-18 0:00:00  1
12  1746    sell    2021-06-18 0:00:00  1
13  1746    sell    2021-06-18 0:00:00  2
14  1746    sell    2021-06-18 0:00:00  2
15  1746    sell    2021-06-18 0:00:00  2
16  1746    sell    2021-06-18 0:00:00  2
17  1746    sell    2021-06-18 0:00:00  2
18  1746    sell    2021-06-18 0:00:00  2
19  1746    sell    2021-06-18 0:00:00  2
20  202 buy 2021-06-19 0:00:00  30
21  202 sell    2021-06-19 0:00:00  1
22  202 sell    2021-06-20 0:00:00  3
23  1746    buy 2021-06-21 0:00:00  45
24  1746    sell    2021-06-22 0:00:00  7
```

The graph shown above is plotted with the code below. But this only plots a single `cod`.

```
# Convert to datetime
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
# Negate Sale rows
df.loc[df['action'].eq('Sale'), 'amt'] *= -1
# Calculate the total amount
df['total_amt'] = df['amt'].cumsum()
# Plot datetime vs total_amt
ax = df.plot(x='datetime', y='total_amt', ylabel='Qty', xlabel='Date')
plt.show()
```

**Question**

How can I group or use other way to plot lines for each `cod` ?

Answer (score 1):

For a `matplotlib` and `pandas` solution three modifications need to be made.

1. Standard `cumsum` will no longer work since the rolling total *per group* is needed. Replace with [`groupby cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) instead.
2. [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) each `cod` in a loop.
3. The `action` column contains the word "sell" not "Sale" so the filter should be `df['action'].eq('sell')`.

```
# Convert to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
# Negate sell rows in action column
df.loc[df['action'].eq('sell'), 'qty'] *= -1

# Create a groupby over `cod`
g = df.groupby('cod')
# Calculate the total amount (per group)
df['total_amt'] = g['qty'].cumsum()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Plot for each group in groubpy
for n, g_df in g:
    g_df.plot(x='date', y='total_amt',
              ylabel='Qty', xlabel='Date',
              ax=ax, label=n)

plt.legend(title='cod')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 1 matplotlib]

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cod': [1746, 202, 1746, 1746, 1746, 202, 202, 1746, 1746, 1746, 1746, 1746,
            1746, 1746, 1746, 1746, 1746, 1746, 1746, 1746, 202, 202, 202, 1746,
            1746],
    'action': ['buy', 'buy', 'sell', 'sell', 'sell', 'sell', 'sell', 'sell',
               'sell', 'sell', 'sell', 'sell', 'sell', 'sell', 'sell', 'sell',
               'sell', 'sell', 'sell', 'sell', 'buy', 'sell', 'sell', 'buy',
               'sell'],
    'date': ['2021-06-15 0:00:00', '2021-06-15 0:00:00', '2021-06-17 0:00:00',
             '2021-06-17 0:00:00', '2021-06-17 0:00:00', '2021-06-17 0:00:00',
             '2021-06-17 0:00:00', '2021-06-18 0:00:00', '2021-06-18 0:00:00',
             '2021-06-18 0:00:00', '2021-06-18 0:00:00', '2021-06-18 0:00:00',
             '2021-06-18 0:00:00', '2021-06-18 0:00:00', '2021-06-18 0:00:00',
             '2021-06-18 0:00:00', '2021-06-18 0:00:00', '2021-06-18 0:00:00',
             '2021-06-18 0:00:00', '2021-06-18 0:00:00', '2021-06-19 0:00:00',
             '2021-06-19 0:00:00', '2021-06-20 0:00:00', '2021-06-21 0:00:00',
             '2021-06-22 0:00:00'],
    'qty': [45, 60, 1, 3, 7, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 30, 1,
            3, 45, 7]
})
```

---

Notice the difference between `cumsum` and `groupby cumsum`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.loc[df['action'].eq('sell'), 'qty'] *= -1
df['cs'] = df['qty'].cumsum()  # Standard cumsum
df['gb_cs'] = df.groupby('cod')['qty'].cumsum()  # Groupby cumsum
```

`df`:

```
     cod action       date  qty   cs  gb_cs
0   1746    buy 2021-06-15   45   45     45
1    202    buy 2021-06-15   60  105     60  # cs has total for both cod
2   1746   sell 2021-06-17   -1  104     44
3   1746   sell 2021-06-17   -3  101     41
4   1746   sell 2021-06-17   -7   94     34
5    202   sell 2021-06-17   -1   93     59  # gb_cs has separate totals per  cod
6    202   sell 2021-06-17   -3   90     56
```

---

An alternative with `seaborn` makes this process simpler by setting the `hue` argument of [`sns.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) instead of creating a groupby to iterate over:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


# DataFrame is the same as above #

# Convert to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
# Negate sell rows in action column
df.loc[df['action'].eq('sell'), 'qty'] *= -1
# Calculate the total amount (per group)
df['total_amt'] = df.groupby('cod')['qty'].cumsum()
# Plot using seaborn with hue param set to `cod`
ax = sns.lineplot(
    data=df, x='date', y='total_amt',
    hue='cod',  # Separate lines based on hue column `cod`
    ci=None,  # Remove Error Shading
    palette='pastel',  # Set Colour Palette
    estimator=None  # Plot all observations (like matplotlib)
)
ax.set(xlabel='Date', ylabel='Qty')
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 2 seaborn]

Comment: Hi Henry, I really appreciate your answers. Thank you.  
Could you show me how to subplot for each `cod`? I'm trying to find a way but couldn't find yet, could you help me?

Comment: Add subplots `fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)` Then change the for loop to `for (n, g_df), ax in zip(g, axes):`

Answer (score 0):

according to the info u posted i rewrite it to:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
# Negate Sale rows
df.loc[df['action'].eq('Sale'), 'amt'] *= -1
# Calculate the total amount
df['total_amt'] = df['amt'].cumsum()
for key, grp in df.groupby(['cod']):
    
    t=ax.plot(grp['datetime'], grp['total_amt'])
    plt.legend(t, [f'total amt {key}'],loc='best')

#ax.set(ylim=[0,100]) <----- if u need to setup y limits
ax.set_ylabel("Qty")
ax.set_xlabel("Date")
```

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't compile... did you compile your code? Checked and tried to change few things to try to make it work but it doesn't compile